# List.Sort and Bubble Sort, which is faster? (Closed)

Tags: c#, sorting

For example, I have a List

```
 List<int> list = new List<int>();

 list.Add(1);
 list.Add(5);
 list.Add(7);
 list.Add(3);
 list.Add(17);
 list.Add(10);
 list.Add(13);
 list.Add(9);
```

1. I use List.Sort method like this

   ```
   private static int Compare(int x, int y)
   {
           if (x == y)
               return 0;
           else if (x > y)
               return -1;
           else
               return 1;
   }
   List.Sort(Compare);
   ```
2. I use bubble sort like this

   ```
    private static void Sort(List<int> list)
    {
       int size = list.Capacity;
       for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
       {
            for (int j = 0; j < (size - i); j++)
            {
              if (list[j] > list[j+1])
              {
                 int temp = list[j];
                 list[j] = list[j+1];
                 list[j+1] = temp;
               }
            }
       }
   }
   ```

My question like the title, I wonder that which is faster?

Thank you

Comment: Considering using `Stopwatch` to test this yourself.

Comment: List.Sort is generally faster than bubble sort because it uses QuickSort. Anyway, for a list of 8 elements the difference is really really negligible... (Also have al look here: http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/)

Comment: Though sorting is a great problem space to explore algorithms and complexity, for getting things done you really want to stick to built-in sorting routines. Only when you identify a case where the built-in sort is inadequate (and you really know what you're doing) should you use a hand-rolled sort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the whole, bubble sort will be slower than almost anything else, including `List.Sort` which is implemented with a quick sort algorithm.

Comment: Could you please give me some explanation?

Comment: @eureka Because List.Sort uses Quicksort, and Quicksort quickly stomps bubble sort! :-). From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Bubble_sort : BS average and worst case are O(n^2), while QS average is O(nlogn) and worst is O(n^2)

Comment: List.Sort, from the documentation: "This method uses Array.Sort, which uses the QuickSort algorithm."  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms details the best, average, and worst case for various sorts.

Answer (score 4):

Bubble sort is simple to implement, but it's not very efficient. The `List.Sort` method uses QuickSort, which is a more complex and also more efficient algorithm.

However, when you have very few items in your list, like in your example, the efficiency of the algorithm doesn't really matter. What matters is how it's implemented and how much overhead there is, so you would just have to use the `Stopwatch` class to time your examples. This will of course only tell you which is faster for the exact list that you are testing, so it's not very useful for choosing an algorithm to use in an application.

Besides, when there are very few items in the list, it doesn't really matter which algorithm is faster because it takes so little time anyway. You should consider how much items there will be in the actual implementation, and if the number of items will grow over time.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [the documentation of `List<T>.Sort()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx):

> On average, this method is an O(n log n) operation, where n is Count; in the worst case it is an O(n ^ 2) operation.

Since bubble sort is O(n ^ 2) (both on average and in the worst case), you can expect `List<T>.Sort()` to be (much) faster on large data sets. The speed of sorting 8 elements (as you have) is usually so minuscule (even using bubble sort), that it doesn't matter what you use.

What could affect the speed in this case is the fact that you use a delegate with `List<T>.Sort()`, but not with your bubble sort. Invoking delegates is relatively slow, so you should try to avoid them if possible when you are micro-optimizing (which you shouldn't do most of the time).